# VBScript .Exec with arguments

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I am trying to use Script.Shell.Exec to run a PowerShell script, and I am running into problems with arguments. A simple command line utility works fine, say

```
strCmd = "%comspec% /c tasklist"
```

And PowerShell without arguments works fine, as in

```
strCmd = "powershell.exe -noLogo -noProfile -executionPolicy bypass -file ""\\Mac\Px\Support\Px Tools\Dev 3.3.#\_Spikes\TestMessage.ps1"""
```

But introduce an argument like this, and it fails.

```
strCmd = "powershell.exe -noLogo -noProfile -executionPolicy bypass -file ""\\Mac\Px\Support\Px Tools\Dev 3.3.#\_Spikes\TestMessage.ps1"" -message:""It's ALIVE!"""
```

I also tried making an array and using the array in .Exec, like this

```
strCmd = "powershell.exe -noLogo -noProfile -executionPolicy bypass -file ""\\Mac\Px\Support\Px Tools\Dev 3.3.#\_Spikes\TestMessage.ps1"" -message:""It's ALIVE!"""
strArgument =  "-message:""It's ALIVE!"""
arrCmd = Array(strCmd, strArgument)
```

I am simply stumped.

Comment: Looks like a quoting issue. Debugging suggestion: Run [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), reduce its filter scope to `powershell.exe` processes and inspect the actual command lines as the process is started.

Comment: Some background for how Windows is parsing command lines internally: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/

Comment: Turns out I had [CmdletBinding()] at the top of my little stub script, because I copy/pasted the parameters section from a function I already had. And CmdletBinding breaks passed parameters from VBS it would seem. Got rid of that and now it works. On to new and different problems! ;)

Comment: Okay, good to hear you've figured it out. I have a feeling that there is a salvageable question here that just needs to be fleshed out. When you break if down more in terms of *how* it fails, exactly, it's possible that you save someone else some time in the future. This enough of an edge case to have not many duplicates yet, I think.